# Is the 100 gems to 1 mithril consistent across all uses of the Premium currency?

Tags: final-fantasy-record-keeper

In Final Fantasy Record Keeper, the player has two alternate currencies to buy freemium content: mithril and gems. While mithril is only earned in-game, gems can be bought for real cash. It seems that in all places 100 gems = 1 mithril.

Is this rate consistent across the entire game?

Answer (score 1):

This is true in most cases, but one notable exception is Relic Draws.

In a relic draw, you can get a x11 for 50 Mythril or 3,000 gems.  A single draw is either 5 Mythril or 300 gems, unless it's your first time drawing *on that banner*, in which case it's 5 Mythril or 100 gems.

Comment: Any way you slice it, $1 or $3 for a ~5% chance at a shiny 5* you actually want is a terrible deal, imho.  2/3rds of the time, you're going to draw 3* that probably won't help unless unless it's really early in the game...

Comment: but these japanese games that use this freemium model have extremely expensive premium currency. Check Love Gems in LLIF, they are almost $1 each. Blame all those kids burning their Otoshidama cash that fast.

Comment: @Mindwin, indeed!  I think it's all nonsense myself, the value of a relic pull to me is more like a nickel and less like $1-3.  But people sink $10k+ into this game - there are special exclusive clubs for their highest paying players...